# Compiler error mysql.h not found

Tags: mysql

On compiling a software I get this error

```
mysql/mysql.h: No such file or directory
```

result of running `mysql_config --include` is

```
-I/usr/local/mysql/include
```

How can I get mysql.h to be detected?

Answer (score 2):

Install mysql development packages on Debian/ubuntu.
sudo apt-get install libmysqld-dev

on CentOs/Redhat (to know who provide - yum provides mysql/mysql.h):
sudo yum install mysql-devel

Answer (score 0):

While building [Kamailio](https://github.com/kamailio/kamailio) from sources on CentOS / Fedora, I encountered `mysql/mysql.h: No such file or directory`

Since my target was MariaDB, installing `mariadb-devel` package helped

```
# yum -y install mariadb-devel
```

Before installing above package, it was necessary for me to clean-up previously installed [MariaDB-client](https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql/connect/clients/mariadb-client/) package.

```
# yum remove MariaDB-client
# yum remove MariaDB-common
# mv /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo.bak
```

If necessary we can get back the original MariaDB-client package after the build process, such as

```
# mv /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo.bak /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo
# yum -y install MariaDB-client
```